# Adverb position in title

Tags: adverb-position

I need to express in the following section heading that the **manner** of adding the units to the Contract is manual and not automatic:

> Adding Units to  a Contract

I would like to do as much as possible to keep the first word of the title "Adding".

**"Adding Manually..."** sounds wrong

**"Adding Units Manually..."** sounds like it could be OK, but I'm not convinced.

**"Adding Units to a Contract Manually"** sounds wrong too.

What would be the best option? Or is the best option to place *Manually* at the beginning?

Comment: I am at a loss to understand the OP. May we please have further and better particulars on the context of the OP and whether or not the "contract" is one that may be defined by law as in the terms and conditions of a contract.

Comment: @PeterPoint, the contract is trivial here and it was just an example from a title that I'm using. I could have said "Adding Stamps to an Envelope". The question is where should the Adverb of Manner be placed in such a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

1 is incorrect

2 and 3 are both correct:

2 underlines the manual part, 3 underlines the contract as important.

*Manually adding units to a contract* emphasises the manual part even more, so if the manner of adding is very important, go for that version